# Rewrite differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

If $h(t+1) = g \cdot h(t) - dh(t)/dx$, then how can you rephrase it to $dh/dt = \dots$ ?

It's an advection equation describing the evolution of a fluid h over time.

Thanks

Comment: is $t(\cdot)$ a function of $x$? or its just a misprint in $dh(t)/dx$?

Comment: No. It's an equation describing the advection of a fluid h over time.

Comment: so there shouldn't be any $x$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
h(t+1) &= g\cdot h(t) + \frac{d h(t)}{dx} &\\
\frac{d h(t)}{dx} &= h(t+1) - g\cdot h(t) & \text{(reorder terms.)}\\
\frac{d h(t)}{dt}\cdot\frac{d t}{dx} &= h(t+1) - g\cdot h(t) & \text{(chain rule.)}\\
\frac{d h(t)}{dt} &= \dot{x}\cdot\left[ h(t+1) - g\cdot h(t)\right] & \frac{d x}{dt} = \dot{x}\\
\end{align}
$$

Disclaimer: I am assumming that you can apply chain rule here, of course.